# How to convert dictionary object into string in python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, converters

i have nested dictionaries and i need to string this dict

dictionary example

```js
data = {
  'filter': {
      'operator': "and",
      'filters': [{
          'operator': "or",
          'filters': [{
              'operator': "and",
              'filters': [{
                  'value': "blue"
              }, {
                  'value': "green"
              }]
          }, {
              'operator': "and",
              'filters': [{
                  'value': "brown"
              }, {
                  'value': "green"
              }]
          }, {
              'value': "green"
          }]
      }, {
          'value': "red"
      }]
    }
}
```

i use recursively function for get 'filters' key but i need detection parentheses level

```
def recursively(dct, field):

    if field in dct:
        yield dct[field]
    for k in dct:
        if isinstance(dct[k], list):
            for i in dct[k]:
                for j in recursively(i, field):
                    yield j
```

finally i need string output

```
>>> recursivaly(data['filter'], 'filters')
# result
((blue AND green) OR (brown AND green) OR green) AND NOT red
```

can you help me?

Comment: the question in the title is misleading, there are infinite ways to display a dictionary as a string, you're looking to convert a specific dictionary structure to represent logical operations

Comment: Why `AND NOT red` at the end? I see no negator operator in your structure.

Comment: @Nicolás  because AND NOT red means search any fields where not contains red

Comment: @PyDroid but there is no 'NOT' in your dictionary

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite really you're right, i use new dict { 'value': "red", 'mean': 'not contains', 'field': 'field_name'},  in 'mean' examples: contains, not contains, equal, not equal and etc

Comment: can you explain in more detail how exactly you determine its `'AND NOT red'` and not just `'NOT red'` ? i dont see the difference in the data structure...

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite can u help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500373/how-to-convert-logical-operators-query-string-to-dictionary-in-python-3

Comment: @Droid was my answer even useful ?

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite i need help pyparsing parser this query string to dict ((blue AND green) OR (brown AND green) OR green) AND NOT red

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```
def dict2str(d):
    if 'value' in d:
        return d['value']
    elif 'operator' in d and 'filters' in d:
        return '(' + (" " + d['operator'].upper() + " ").join(map(dict2str, d['filters'])) + ')'
    else:
        raise Exception('invalid dictionary')
```

basically recursively go down the dictionary and return the string representation of each node. to simplify the second `if` here's an equivalent code that is more explicit:

```
def dict2str(d):
    if 'value' in d:
        return d['value']
    elif 'operator' in d and 'filters' in d:

        operator = " " + d['operator'].upper() + " "

        filters = []
        for filt in d['filters']:
            filters.append(dict2str(filters))

        ret = ""
        ret += "("
        ret += operator.join(filters)
        ret += ")"

        return ret
    else:
        raise Exception('invalid dictionary')
```

the `"AND NOT red"` part got me confused but i hope this helps