# how to convert logical operators query string to dictionary in Python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, mapping

i have query string and i need to convert json object, as shown below

```
((blue AND green) OR (brown AND green) OR green) AND NOT red
```

```js
{
  "filter": {
"operator": "and",
"filters": [{
    "operator": "or",
    "filters": [{
        "operator": "and",
        "filters": [{
            "means": "contains",
            "value": "blue"
          },
          {
            "means": "contains",
            "value": "green"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "operator": "and",
        "filters": [{
            "means": "contains",
            "value": "brown"
          },
          {
            "means": "contains",
            "value": "green"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "means": "contains",
        "value": "green"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "means": "not contains",
    "value": "red"
  }
]
  }
}
```

can you help me? how to convert query to same dict, i need good solutions for mappings

Comment: Depending on the syntax you want, it would be something like: 

{'field': {'$and': [{'$or':[ {'$and':['BLUE','GREEN']}, {'$and':['BROWN', 'GREEN']}, 'GREEN']}, {'$ne':'red'}]}} for mongodb

Comment: @PyDroid- You may want to update your question so that it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: any help from anybody?

Comment: what would you expect the dictionary to look for something like this: `((blue AND green)  OR NOT (brown AND red) `in other words, were these expressions somehow simplified using de morgan's laws ?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite can u help me, show me simple example

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite please, can u help me?